# update ruby in mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I do not have RVM installed. I want to install ruby 2.5.1. When I install RVM with "rvm install ruby-2.5.1", I get the error: "-bash: rvm: command not found".

My default ruby version in my iMac is 2.3.3

When I run "ruby -v" I'm getting this,

```
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]
```

But the latest version is 2.5.1

When I try to install rvm it's getting this message.

NOTE: GPG version 2.1.17 have a bug which cause failures during fetching keys from remote server. Please downgrade or upgrade to newer version (if available) or use the second method described above.

I tried these to solve my problem URL's to solve, but no use.

http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/

https://blog.arkency.com/which-ruby-version-am-i-using-how-to-check/

When I enter "gem env"

```
RubyGems Environment:
 - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.3 (2016-11-21 patchlevel 222) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/research/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/research/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-17
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0
     - /Users/research/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
```

Comment: try this, http://codingpad.maryspad.com/2017/04/29/update-mac-os-x-to-the-current-version-of-ruby/

Comment: @ PPL when I try this command curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable.  I'm getting NOTE: GPG version 2.1.17 have a bug which cause failures during fetching keys from remote server. Please downgrade or upgrade to newer version (if available) or use the second method described above.

Comment: @iOS Have you googled the error: "NOTE: GPG version 2.1.17 have a bug which cause failures during fetching keys from remote server. Please downgrade or upgrade to newer version (if available) or use the second method described above."? What have you found? What have you tried? I could make some suggestions, but I'd basically just be copy+pasting some information from a quick google search, which seems really counterproductive.

Comment: When I run this command "gpg2 --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D3C0E3", Getting -bash: gpg2: command not found. And when I run "curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg --import -", Getting gpg: key 3804BB82D39DE3: 47 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 3804BB82D39DE3: "Michal Papis (RVM signing) <mpapis@gmail.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1

Comment: Using homebrew to install `rvm` or `rbenv` (my personal choice) is easier and avoids this.

Comment: @iOS Please can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50368963/edit) with a clear description of what you tried (where did you get that information?), along with the results. Drip-feeding information in the comments makes it much harder for people to properly understand your question.

Comment: The `gem env`, `ruby -v` and links you provided don't really affect the problem. The **only** information above that's really crucial is: "I do not have RVM installed. I want to install ruby 2.5.1. When I install RVM with <command>, I get the error: <full error message>. I found similar problems here: <link>. When I tried that, I got this error: <full error>".

Comment: @Tom Lord thank you, I updated my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally i updated successfully with the help of these links...

https://www.computersnyou.com/5307/setup-homebrew-and-rvm-on-mac-osx-10-11-ei-capitan/

I typed this command,

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

After that i used this command,

```
type rvm | head -n 1
```

It's printing "rvm is a function"

After that i used this command,

```
rvm install ruby-head
```

After some time RVM installed.

When i type this command

```
ruby -v
```

I'm getting this message "ruby 2.6.0dev (2018-05-16 trunk 63444) [x86_64-darwin17]"